# TSQL Coalesce Row values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, azure-synapse

I have currently have a very simple query that simply SELECTs and produces the following

```
| Date       | Name             | ID      |
|------------|------------------|---------|
| 2018-11-07 | McDonald's       | 1046226 |
| 2018-01-22 | NULL             | 1046226 |
| 2019-01-07 | Dell             | 1069285 |
| 2019-01-09 | Dell Corporation | 1069285 |
```

What I want to do is SELECT the earliest date row for each ID, using MIN

But the problem I have is that if the earliest row has a NULL name, I want to coalesce its name from another row

```
| Date       | Name             | ID      |
|------------|------------------|---------|
| 2018-01-22 | McDonald's       | 1046226 |
| 2019-01-07 | Dell             | 1069285 |
```

I have no idea if there is any syntax can help me here, can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `coalesce`:

```
select 
  min(t.date) Date,
  coalesce(
    (
      select name from tablename where id = t.id and date = (
        select min(date) from tablename where id = t.id
      )
    ),
    max(name)
  ) name,
  t.id ID
from tablename t
group by t.id
```

Comment: I think your simplest solution worked before you edited it, when it was just MAX(NAME) and MIN(DATE)

Comment: Yes it did work, but in case the name was not null then it would get another name from another row.

Comment: The current code gets another name only if the name with min date is null.

Comment: Oh I see, so in my example above, it would not be necessarily be Dell but Dell Corporation for the second row (if Dell Corporation > Dell). I think that situation would still be fine. Thanks!

Comment: Use the version that suits you.

Comment: Why use one copy of the table (eg with the `RANK` and `ROW_NUMBER` techniques) when you can use three!?  Note the difference in behaviour for  `RANK` and `ROW_NUMBER`.

Comment: @wBob are you sure that this comment belongs to this answer?

Comment: Hey @forpas, yes.  This question relates to a product called Azure SQL Data Warehouse (tagged `azure-sqldw`) which is an MPP product.  As such it often features tables with billions of rows.  Therefore it's even more important than ever to make efficient choices when creating queries on this product.  Working on this product and faced a query which either used three copies of a table, or one, I would pick the query using one copy.  To put it another way, in my ADW test table I generated for this question which has 100 million rows, my query finished in 20 seconds and yours is still running ...

Comment: @wBob I suppose since your answer is here, the OP will see it and test it just like he tested mine. So you have nothing to worry about.

Comment: @forpas good to know!  I think their comment "I think that situation would still be fine" covers it for me.  Oh, hang on, your query failed with my test data after 30 mins - `Subquery returned more than 1 value...`.  I sure hope the OP doesn't have that situation.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, `row_number()` is used for this:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by id order by date) as seqnum
      from <your query here> t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

A simpler method that can be slightly slower is:

```
select top (1) with ties . . .
from . . .
. . .
order by row_number() over (partition by id order by date)
```

Answer (score 0):

Two methods tested on Azure SQL Data Warehouse using a CTE

```
;WITH cte AS
(
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY [Date] ) rn
FROM #tmp
)
SELECT [Date], name, ID 
FROM cte 
WHERE rn = 1
```

Or if you wanted to CTAS your remaining data into a new table, you can combine CTEs and CTAS in Azure SQL Data Warehouse, eg

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.yourNewTable
WITH
(
    CLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE INDEX,
    DISTRIBUTION = HASH( ID )
    -- Optionally add partition scheme here if required
)
AS
WITH cte AS
(
SELECT
    [Date],
    MIN(Name) OVER( PARTITION BY ID ) name,
    ID,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY [Date] ) rn
FROM dbo.yourTable
)
SELECT [Date], name, ID 
FROM cte 
WHERE rn = 1
OPTION ( LABEL = 'CTAS : Dedupe' );
```

Note the difference in behaviour for `RANK` and `ROW_NUMBER`.